# How to return a value from a container which runs a python script?

Tags: python, docker

I have python script that takes a path to folder containing a few files as argument and does some calculations and std out the result on the command prompt.
Now I want to containerize this script and return the result instead of just printing it out. Once returned I want to remove the container as well.
I thought of capturing it from the printed output, but I don't think it is a good idea. I also saw a method by printing it out on a text file outside of container and reading from it when required.

What is the best way to do this other than these methods? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your current code prints to stdout, so why cannot Docker do that as well? In other words, you *need* a file, then your current code should probably do that before it's part of a container?